# Pending promise after pushing to array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

The function below is supposed to return an array of objects. translationByLang is returning a Promise stored then in the "result" variable.
In order to map my "result" I am using **Promise.all** to push the values to **myArray** but when I console.log the value of **myArray** I still have an array of Promises.
Note that if I console log the response inside await Promise real data are shown, not Promise data...

```
async function getData() {

    let translationByLang = Object.values(translationArray.reduce((acc, 
     {field,lang,text}) => {
      acc[lang] = acc[lang] || {lang}
      acc[lang][field] = text
      return acc
    },{}))

    let result = translationByLang;

    if(result.length < 2){
      let obj = {"lang":"en", "name":"Documento mancante","pdf_url":""}
      result.push(obj)
    }

    let myArray=[]
    await Promise.all(result).then(res => {
      myArray.push(res)
    });
    return myArray

  }
```

Here is a screenshot that explains the whole thing.
[image]

Comment: "*The function below is supposed to return an array of objects*" - it cannot. It's asynchronous. The best it can do is return a promise for the array of objects.

Comment: What you need to change is `const arr = await getCorrectArray()`.

Comment: You should `.then` on getData to have the correct array

Comment: You either use `.then` or `await` - don't combine them. I don't even understand why this is an `async` function, `result` does not seem like a Promise to me. Create an example repo/fiddle that we can run ourselves, it'll be easier to debug.

Comment: async function was not needed. Thanks for your help. My understanding of async /await is still poor